# Is it possible Looping in trigger

Tags: sql

My Trigger is on the table affected here:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET VALUE = @VALUE
```

now i execute the above query means trigger will execute now

```
TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
.
.
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET VALUE = @VALUE 
.
.
END
```

now 2nd update query execute means again trigger will execute or not this is my question.

Comment: If it's the same table, it will either give you an error (circular), or it will crash in one of three horrible ways. Different DBMS's deal with this diffrently.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

In SQL Server, this is "direct trigger recursion"

This is controlled by 2 things

- "nested triggers" option at the server level which controls all trigger recursion.
  See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178101.aspx
- `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` at the database level which controls direct recursion. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx

For full details, see [Create Nested Triggers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190739.aspx)

Note that this will loop until [`@@NESTLEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187371.aspx) reaches 32